# Trouble running subversion through PHP's exec

Tags: php, svn

I can run an svn command from the command line but not from within a PHP script. Significantly, I can run the PHP script on my Mac and it returns the expected data just fine but when I upload it to my Linux server it won't work (from within PHP... I can run the svn command from the terminal). I'm pretty sure this is a user or permission issue of some sort.

I can run (from command line):

```
svn log http://whatever.com/svn/foo
```

but none of the following work (run separately... not all together like this):

```
exec('svn log http://whatever.com/svn/foo');
exec('svn log http://whatever.com/svn/foo',$out);
exec('/usr/bin/svn log http://whatever.com/svn/foo');
```

However this works:

```
exec('ls');
```

I assume the problem is that when I run from the command line I am running as root whereas when I run from PHP I am running as the apache user (www-data)? Perhaps? Any suggestions on how to be able to run `exec('svn log http://whatever.com/svn/foo');`?

Changing permissions to 777 (just trying to get it working!) does not help.

Comment: No error. If I `var_dump($out)` I get all of the data I expect on one machine and an empty array on the other machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of threads that I think might help:

[Thread 1](http://old.nabble.com/problem-in-running-svn-command-through-php-on-CentOS-td14436616.html) (read as there is more):

```
$cmd = '/usr/bin/svn list --config-dir /some/place file:///var/subversion/devfoundry/ 2>&1';
exec($cmd, $output); 
$output = implode("\n", $output) . "\n";
echo $output;
```

[Thread 2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#79061):

> The Subversion error "svn: Can't
>   recode string" can be caused by the
>   locale being wrong.  Try
>
> ```
> <?php
>     putenv('LANG=en_US.UTF-8');
> ?>
> ```
>
> (or whatever your preferred locale is)
>   before you call shell_exec()

[Thread](https://github.com/geoffrey/PHPInteractiveShell) 3: PHP Interactive Shell

Comment: This got me somewhere. Following the thread 1 instructions gave me "Error validating server certificate..." thing is, when I manually ran this svn command from the command line I told it to Permanently accept the certificate yet I still get this warning (when run from PHP... not from terminal)

Comment: Probably because PHP is running as another user. (Nobody perhaps) and the settings file saying to trust that cert doesn't exist for Nobody.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can use a svn client for php. Here is a good one
http://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/

Comment: I've tried using that and had mixed results. The older version of it (http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4270-PHP-Retrieve-files-from-an-SVN-repository-in-pure-PHP.html) actually works better than this newer version. I got the old version working (mostly) but it has some bugs I couldn't track down so I tried the newer version that you linked to and got nothing but error after error. I wish it worked well but it seems not to.

Answer (score 3):

When you run Subversion from the command line, you are running it as yourself. That is, you are the user logged in and running the command.

If you are running Php from a webpage, it is the user who is running the Apache httpd daemon (which could be "apache", "www", "runwww", etc. depending upon the platform). The user running the PHP script may not have read/write permissions to the Subversion repository.

You have two ways of solving this:

- Provide your program with user credentials via the `--username` and `--password` command line parameters.
- Setup the user running httpd with Subversion credentials. Once it is done, it'll never have to be done again. This way, your PHP code doesn't contain login credentials.