# Creating a PHP page that runs a release script on Unix

Tags: php, unix

I've just completed writing some release scripts on my client's new server that creates an SVN tag and checks it out, creating all the specific symlinks and releases it onto either their production or staging websites.

My client quite likes getting his hands dirty, and is increasingly comfortable getting under the hood and making PHP/HTML changes when I'm focusing on something else.  He's actually quite good, and I'm encouraging him to continue because it's good for both of us and he doesn't annoy me by making simple or annoying errors.

I'm going to set him up with a SVN client so he can commit his changes, but the only thing outstanding from the process is allowing him to release those changes to staging and production.  Of course, I can give him access to the server via. SSH and walk him through the process, but that seems like it has the potential to go seriously wrong at some point.

I'm thinking of setting up a PHP password-protected page that will let him run those scripts by clicking a button.

So, I've two questions:

a) Is the approach I'm taking with a PHP page to expose the release scripts reasonable, and

b) What is the best way to implement this type of page in PHP?  The script is a straight-forward shell script

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) in PHP to run whichever commands you need to run. If you want him to provide an SVN check in message, then you'll probably be including user input like this:

```
exec("svn commit -m '$message'");
// Perform more exec() commands as needed
```

At which point you need to be careful — as the PHP.net page on `exec()` says:

> "When allowing user-supplied data to be passed to this function, use escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd() to ensure that users cannot trick the system into executing arbitrary commands."

[Check out the PHP.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for more information.

Comment: Not sure if this would work as the Apache user 'Nobody' would be running a SVN command, maybe permission issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685164/trouble-running-subversion-through-phps-exec related

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, try Capistranto https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano

Comment: Yeah, just throw some Ruby on the problem and he'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I took a look into Capistrano and some supporting documentation, but as far as I could see it still requires command-line experience/access, which is what I'm trying to avoid with my client.  Did I miss something?

Comment: We setup Capistrano were I work. There was some command-line experience to set it up. However it can all be triggered with one command, which could be called from a php script if need be.

Answer (score 0):

I think of 2 ways to do that :

- execute your script from php with system or exec, but it needs to be possible
- your php script creates a token (file) and a cronjob looks for it frequently and runs your script if token is present (more secure)

Answer (score 0):

Part A of your question is kind of subjective, so I'll just say that I think it is reasonable. Part B of your question is pretty simple. Basically you just need to [execute](https://www.php.net/exec) an external command via PHP. This can become more difficult if you need it to run as a different user than your Apache setup is running as.

In it's most basic form it is as simple as:

```
exec('your command here');
```

That said you probably want to use some form submit buttons to trigger those commands.

```
<?php
if ($is_authorized && $push_to_staging) {
  // execute the command to push the repo to staging.
}
?>
```

Be sure to escape any user input with [`escapeshellarg`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).